# has_one relation building but on page load deletes old entry

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, forms, foreign-key-relationship

I am trying to make a has one for reviews. If a service is provided for someone then they can `review` that `reservation`/service.  so `reservations` has a `has_one :review`.

[image]
Reservation model:

```rails
has_one :review, :dependent => :destroy
```

routes.rb

```rails
resources :reservations do
resources :reviews, only: [:create, :destroy]
end
```

This is what my form looks like:

```html
<%= form_for([reservation, reservation.build_review]) do |f| %>

  <h>How would you rate your reviser?</h>
  <div style="">
    <div style="display:inline-block;" id="user_stars"></div>
  </div>


  <div class="" style="margin-top:5px;margin-bottom:3px;">
    <label>Comment:</label>
    <%= f.text_area :comment, rows: 3, class: "form-control" %>
  </div>
  <%= f.hidden_field :reviser_id, value: reservation.reviser.id %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :reservation_id, value: reservation.id %>

      <div class="actions">
        <%= f.submit "Comment", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
      </div>

      <% end %>
```

Here is my reviews controller `create` action

```rails
def create

    @review = current_user.reviews.create(review_params)

    redirect_to completed_assignments_reservations_path, notice: "Thank You!! Your review has been submitted!"
end
```

Update of what i know!!:

- Whenever i add the redirect_to the entry does not get saved to db however when i remove this. the db entry saves in the db.  The redirect_to is messing with it even when i added `if @review.save` the redirect_to was messing it up.. so what could be the reason for this??
- After thinking and looking at it more iv come to the conclusion of why it is doing this but no solution so far. I am using a partial called `_form.html.erb` partials load when the page first loads even in a dropdown, which is where the form is being pulled out from. so when i redirect back to that page the review gets deleted because it acts like the new page and deletes the entry to get a new entry.  How can I prevent the deletion on page load new and instead in order for a new entry to be made the user has to submit the form, then the old db value will be replaced.
- All in all not on `page load` but instead `on form submit`
- I added `, force_non_association_create: true` to my form to see if that would stop from auto submitting of pageload. Still having the same problem I will check if it will work on the link for the dropdown.. i think this will be the solution.
- I added `:force_non_association_create => true` to just about everything and still doesnt work.. i took away the redirect_to to make sure it still worked without and it.  I also added `:force_non_association_create => true` to the redirect_to just in case i have it added everywhere pretty much still nothin...

Here is a part on the `completed_reservations.html.erb` the loaded on link_to partial that loads _forms.html.erb:

```html
<div style="margin-top:30px;">
  <%= link_to 'javascript:;', :class => "request-popover", :"data-placement" => "left", :force_non_association_create => true, :rel => "popover", :"data-content" => "#{render 'reviews/form', reservation: reservation}", :"data-class" => "review-form-popover" do %>
    <i style="font-size:40px;color:#45d1b8;" class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    <% end %>
      <script>
        $(function() {
          $('.request-popover').popover({
            template: '<div class="popover special-class2"><div class="arrow"></div><div class="popover-inner"><h3 class="popover-title"></h3><div class="popover-content"><p></p></div></div></div>',
            html: true
          });
        });
      </script>
</div>
```

Comment: A `302` is not an error, it is the code that is sent to the browser to tell it to do a redirect which is just what you asked for in your  controller. Without a redirect you would normally get a `400` but there are lots of other codes. see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes

Comment: Thats good to know ty! Then the main problem im having is that there is nothing showing up in the db. As if it gets deleted after it has been made.